# Appending data to existing NetCDF file using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf

There is a [Raster to NetCDF tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/multidimension-toolbox/raster-to-netcdf.htm) for converting raster to NetCDF using ArcGIS.

How do I append raster data as dimension to NetCDF using ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

[netCDF4](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) is a python module than enables 
 you to modify add and create netcdf files.

Comment: While this does not answer the original question at all (which asked for an ArcPy solution), it is a valuable hint that you can do this with open-source community Python tools, too.